# Free will as ignorance of future decisions

Tags: free-will, determinism, decision-theory

I find the following definition of free will appealing:

An entity that has free will...

- always pays an exploration-exploitation tradeoff
- is capable of higher order thought (i.e. it has an internal model of its own reasoning),
- can assert (using its higher order thought) that it does not know *now* how it will decide *later*, even if it had all sensory input available right now.

The main way how free will may arise would then be the incompleteness and inaccuracy of the internal model of reasoning:

- Because of the exploration-exploitation tradeoff, the entity will not think arbitrarily far in the future, so in general when reasoning *now* (at `t_0`) about its decisions at *later* (`t_1`), it will usually only plan until `t_2`, whereas when reasoning *later* about its decisions, it will plan until `t_3` (even further than `t_2`).
- The internal model of its own reasoning is simplified, idealized. (For example, a human might believe always to act perfectly rationally, but has in fact preferences that are incompatible with their own personal concept of rationality.)

My question is basically which camp in the free will discussion you would place this definition, or more specifically whether this definition has already been studied. I guess it is sort of a compatibilist, Bayesian viewpoint, but still I couldn't find a reference that traces free will to inaccurate higher order thought.

Maybe allow me one comment: This is not the standard argument of "The world is probabilistic from the viewpoint of the entity's unlimited knowledge, thus it cannot predict its future actions, hence free will." The difference in my definition is that I presume that the entity will not predict its own decisions even if all sensory input until that later point in time is known. Of course one may still argue that brains are thermodynamic and thus the decision process of a human is necessarily probabilistic, and this is exactly my second point (simplified internal model of reasoning).

Comment: It seems that you present your personal definition of free-will, and then add some of your thoughts as an ad-hoc explanation. -  Otherwise please give a reference, e.g., from https://plato.stanford.edu/ for the definition and some corresponding arguments.

Comment: This does not work as a *definition* of free will even on [compatibilist views](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/compatibilism/#ContComp). These features may help explain seeming unpredictability of behavior, but free will as such is not about predictability, that is a side issue. It is traditionally associated with "freedom to do otherwise" or "acting according to desires", etc. Also, the "higher thought" requirements are too rationalistic. "Asserting" and "knowing" are too strong for animals, but they presumably have some sort of free will in the traditional sense.

Comment: This may make you free from your past self, but that's not a good thing. It suggests either your personality can change arbitrarily from one moment to the next, or your decisions aren't based on your personality traits. Although the latter is also a problem with libertarian free will.

Comment: @Conifold Concerning the traditional definition of free will as "freedom to do otherwise": Do you agree that this definition is rather useless because one can never reconstruct for a person the same situation for decision? At least, the decision maker knows that it is the second and not the original situation. This knowledge may influence the decision.

Comment: @JoWehler No. If our inability to reconstruct situations exactly was a forbidding obstacle we would have no experimental science. We always exclude only some confounders and control only some factors, but that does not prevent us from testing dependence on them in experiments. But I do not think this is even a definition, rather intuitive heuristic that may help lead to one eventually. The concept of free will is not ripe for definition yet, but that is the case with most pre-scientific concepts before we develop a theory of them. Theories have to start somewhere, often vague and tangled.

Comment: *later*, "it" doesn't know..., but "always pays an exploration-exploitation tradeoff", .so the "payment" changes with "same input"? how that? "it" seems confused/undetermined!;)

Comment: besides: there is no (two times) "same input" in this world, neither "input in advance"...all "input", that "we" get is historical...

Comment: @Conifold Of course we can reconstruct in many cases of experimental science all relevant boundary conditions. Notably in quantum mechanics, where “state” is the result of a preparation. But for free will the mental state (conscious and unconscious) of the person is a relevant boundary condition. One cannot assure that the decision maker is in the same mental state at each repetition of the decision. – I agree that a useful definition of free will is under discussion but has not yet reached general acceptance.

Comment: This question is not about philosophy. In computer science, deterministic algorithms plan in various ways with uncertainty in incomplete knowledge, also having internal models of reasoning. This neither makes the algorithm free nor having will.

Comment: @JoWehler We can recreate "boundary conditions" only to finite precision even in the best of circumstances in physics, in biology or psychology experiments that is often an unaffordable luxury and there are plenty of confounding factors we cannot control. The solution is multiple runs and statistics. Neuroscience should not be held to a standard of perfection that is moot elsewhere, people with their mental states are not singularly special. Free will heuristics were enough for Libet to design his experiments, flawed as they were, and neuroscientists are working to improve on them.

Answer (score -1):

You are making things unnecessarily complicated. A better definition for free will would be simply "the ability to make decisions".

Speculating on future decisions is quite pointless. Better concentrate on decisions made now based on knowledge about the past and plans about the future.

Comment: "the ability to make decisions" would not even be a definition of will, let alone free will.

Comment: @rus9384 Why not? When you can decide what you do, then you are doing according to your own free will. Free from the wills of others, free from any causal necessity.

Comment: "free"="0$"(!), "will"="all $"? ;) ..so it is sort of "economical oxymoron"!?

Comment: My lawyer wrote me a free will pro bono.

Comment: You are criticising that particular definition, but this was not the question. My question is whether this definition has already been studied, and how it is related to other definitions on the landscape of the free will discussion.